# How to develop a remote access tool for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, remote-access

I need to develop a remote access too so that our support staff can take control of users' devices and fix problems.

I'm not sure where to start. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, connectivity, you can try udp connection but it may be
unavailable since there are issues with carrier support, static ip, firewall blocking etc (still if it's internal project, there are BES, BIS and everything, it's the best choice). You can try to listen for data from device over tcp or even http, check for changes and proceed new commands. This may be also achieved over web-services.

Next I would advice to focus on the security, crypting and privileges.

And of course stuff you may need to implement this support:

- Scanning active applications
- Event logging (and sending to server)
- Screen capture (and sending to server)
- Event injections (to control user input from server)

After all you will have to setup application permissions.

[SO - Sockets and Processes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45623/sockets-and-processes-in-java)
[SO - Web services Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735271/web-services-security)
[SO - BlackBerry - background application to listen starts and foreground app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968142/blackberry-background-application-to-listen-starts-and-foreground-app)
[SO - Get a list of all installed applications on Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372791/get-a-list-of-all-installed-applications-on-blackberry)
[SO - BlackBerry - Simulate a KeyPress event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292896/blackberry-simulate-a-keypress-event)
[SO - Screenshot tool for BlackBerry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875978/screenshot-tool-for-blackberry)